# PyTorch model doesn't seem to optimize

Tags: python, pytorch

I have the following code which runs just fine, but the tensors from the model itself always seem to be close to about .5, it just doesn't seem to go very far from there. I know that I definitely have enough epochs, so what's going wrong?

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from tqdm import tqdm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import keras
import sys
devicet = 'cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'
device = torch.device(devicet)
if devicet == 'cpu':
  print ('Using CPU')
else:
  print ('Using GPU')
cuda0 = torch.device('cuda:0')
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.step1 = nn.Linear(5, 25)
        self.step2 = nn.Linear(25, 50)
        self.step3 = nn.Linear(50, 100)
        self.step4 = nn.Linear(100, 100)
        self.step5 = nn.Linear(100, 10)
        self.step6 = nn.Linear(10, 1)
    def forward(self, x):
      x = F.relu(x)
      x = self.step1(x)
      x = self.step2(x)
      x = self.step3(x)
      x = self.step4(x)
      x = self.step5(x)
      x = self.step6(x)
      return (x)
net = Net()
x = torch.rand(50,5)
y = torch.rand(50, 1)
x.to(devicet)
y.to(devicet)
learning_rate = 1e-4
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)
loss_fn = torch.nn.MSELoss()
acc_list = []
for i in range(1000):
    y_pred = net(x)
    loss = loss_fn(y_pred, y)
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    acc_list.append(abs(net(x).detach().numpy()[0]-y.detach().numpy()[0]))
    sys.stdout.write("\rEpoch: {0}, Tensor Difference: {1}".format(len(acc_list), net(x).detach().numpy()[0]-y.detach().numpy()[0]))
    sys.stdout.flush()
    with torch.no_grad():
        for param in net.parameters():
            param -= learning_rate * param.grad
print ('\nFinished training in {} epochs.'.format(len(acc_list)))
plt.plot(range(len(acc_list)),acc_list)
plt.show()
print (net(x).detach().numpy()[0:5])
print (y.detach().numpy()[0:5])
```

Keep in mind that I'm fairly new to PyTorch and this is my first self designed model, not just the built in Sequential.

Comment: you apply the non-linear activation `F.relu` only to the input. You should apply it instead after every linear layer.

Comment: The question is - do you understand WHY?

Comment: Not particularly, no, I was just doing some research on what ReLU does, but I'm having some trouble understanding.

Comment: It's less about the ReLU itself, and more about the lack of activation: try to think of only two linear layers: What is the function (mathematically) they implement, with and without an activation?

Comment: I suggest you [play](https://playground.tensorflow.org/#activation=linear&batchSize=10&dataset=circle&regDataset=reg-plane&learningRate=0.03&regularizationRate=0&noise=0&networkShape=4&seed=0.72006&showTestData=false&discretize=false&percTrainData=50&x=true&y=true&xTimesY=false&xSquared=false&ySquared=false&cosX=false&sinX=false&cosY=false&sinY=false&collectStats=false&problem=classification&initZero=false&hideText=false) with it: see what happens if you have a "linear" activation (i.e., no activation at all) vs. ReLU activation

Answer (score 0):

In the forward function, all that was required was to add the `x = F.relu(x)` after each linear layer. Thank you again [Shai](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67584284/pytorch-model-doesnt-seem-to-optimize?noredirect=1#comment119458153_67584284)!